# Disable Qt traces on Ubuntu system

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu

For some reason, whatever Qt-based application I start from a terminal issues some traces I would like to disable.

Example:

```
$> qtcreator
Got bus address:  "unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-vDsC42Ojkq,guid=dc44d5a0e955ae51a4dbbdc100001ce3" 
Connected to accessibility bus at:  "unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-vDsC42Ojkq,guid=dc44d5a0e955ae51a4dbbdc100001ce3" 
Registered DEC:  true 
Registered event listener change listener:  true
...
...
```

Do anyone know how to get rid of these messages?
Thanks.

Comment: does uninstalling qt-at-spi help? Which Qt, qt-at-spi, and qt versions do you use? Also, which ubuntu version do you use, which architecture, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Laszlo Papp comment, I took a look to qt-at-spi setup...

```
$> locate qt-at-spi
/usr/share/doc/qt-at-spi
/usr/share/doc/qt-at-spi/README
/usr/share/doc/qt-at-spi/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/qt-at-spi/copyright
/var/lib/dpkg/info/qt-at-spi:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/qt-at-spi:amd64.md5sums
```

Let's see what README file tells:

```
$> more /usr/share/doc/qt-at-spi/README
Qt AT-SPI2 bridge
=================

This is a Qt plugin that bridges Qt's accessibility API to AT-SPI2.
With recent versions of AT-SPI2 this should make Qt applications accessible
with the help of tools such as Gnome's Orca screen-reader.

Switch gnome to use at-spi2:
gconftool-2 --set /desktop/gnome/interface/at-spi-dbus --type bool true
gconftool-2 --set /desktop/gnome/interface/at-spi-corba --type bool false

To run gnome apps with at-spi2 in a non-gnome session:
export GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge

Qt will only load this plugin when the environment variable
QT_ACCESSIBILITY is set to 1.
```

And like the README says, QT_ACCESSIBILITY environment variable was set to 1 on my machine.

So the **solution is**:

- **EITHER to remove qt-at-spi module**:

```
    sudo dpkg --purge qt-at-spi
```

- **OR to unset this variable**, which, after a quick research was set in /etc/X11/Xsession.d/90qt-a11y script, **based on gnome settings**:

```
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface toolkit-accessibility false
```

Thank you Laszlo!

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 32bit, Unity, In Anki program I wanted to add a photo and received this: ASSERT failure in : "Got an update for an invalid inteface. Investigate this.", file atspiadaptor.cpp, line 899. After removing qt-at-spi module, everything works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I usually redirect all output of GUI apps started from a terminal:

```
$> qtcreator >/dev/null &
```

Comment: In this case, I would suggest &>/dev/null to redirect both standard and stderr to /dev/null (traces are printed to stderr).
... But definitely, this is not a solution!
I'm asking because it used not to behave like that. Since this time, I've developped QT applications, and maybe I enabled some specific debug configuration by mistake. The thing is that I cannot revert this change now...
In any case, this is not really a big deal if I cannot find a solution! ;-)
Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Dave: I suggest to remove this reply.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to remove the qt-at-spi package or use `QT_ACCESSIBILITY=0 qtcreator`.

Here you can find the official README under the KDE umbrella for details:

https://projects.kde.org/projects/playground/accessibility/qtatspi/repository/revisions/master/entry/README